# What game is displayed in this photo with a character giving me a 'squeezie'?

Tags: game-identification

I was on a discord and someone posted this (and asking them what game it is didn't result in an answer, neither did google reverse image search), and I wonder what game it's from:

[image: Character gives a squeezie]

Looking at the screen edge and screen res, I believe that it's a game for Nintendo 3DS, though I can't seem to find out what the game is.

Does anyone know what game this is?

Comment: For future reference, [quote marks in Google searches are your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i%27ll+give+you+a+squeezieee%22).

Comment: @jpmc26 ahhh, I tried it without quote marks and got nothing but guess I should've tried with quote marks too. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @jpmc26 That google search gives me no results that would even be remotely helpful in finding the game. :/

Comment: @Pyritie You need to click the `Search instead for "I'll give you a squeezieee"` link - Google's trying to be helpful and searching for what it thinks you meant to type rather than what you actually typed.

Comment: Oh! there it is

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That screenshot is from [*Final Fantasy Crystal Chronicles: Ring of Fates*](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_Crystal_Chronicles:_Ring_of_Fates) for the Nintendo DS.

[image: Final Fantasy Crystal Chronicles NDS box cover art]

The line can be found in [this transcription](https://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/925295-final-fantasy-crystal-chronicles-ring-of-fates/faqs/71105) of the game's script.

The character talking in the screenshot is [Meeth Crym](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Meeth_Crym).